# React Native: Issue with Button Component Rendering Blank in Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm encountering an issue in my React Native project where the Button component appears blank on Android, despite setting the title prop. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Click Me" onPress={() => handlePress()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function handlePress() {
  console.log("Button clicked!");
}
```

I've checked the documentation and other resources, and it seems like I'm using the **`Button`** component correctly. However, when I run the app on an Android emulator, the button is rendering without any text. The onPress function is triggered correctly, but the text is not visible.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can point me in the right direction to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Attach screenshot of your Android device, also mention react-native version that you are using.